# weniger as an adverb

Tags: meaning, adverb

I have encountered this sentence:

> Man muss ab und zu auch mal eine weniger gerechte Aufgabenteilung im Beruf hinnehmen.

Can you please translate the part containing "weniger" literally to English? And what would be the difference in meaning if it was:

> Man muss ab und zu auch mal eine weniger**e** gerechte Aufgabenteilung im Beruf hinnehmen.

Comment: "less just/fair"; the second version doesn't sound correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Man muss ab und zu auch mal eine weniger gerechte Aufgabenteilung im Beruf hinnehmen.

First the meaning as literal as possible:  »One has to accept once in a while a less just task distribution in the job.«

The »weniger« is the comparative form of the word »wenig« which is an adverb and thus refers to »gerecht«, so it means »less just«.  If it was an adjective, it would refer to the noun »Aufgabenteilung« which clearly doesn't make much sense in this context but would be possible in general (»a lesser task distribution«).

In German we wouldn't use »wenigere Aufgabenteilung«, though because »wenig« isn't used as an adjective at all.  It only is used as an adverb (and the comparative form »weniger« can be used to express »minus« as a conjunction but we don't have that case here).  To express something like »lesser task distribution« we would use e.g. »geringere Aufgabenverteilung«.

So, the sentence

> Man muss ab und zu auch mal eine weniger**e** gerechte Aufgabenteilung im Beruf hinnehmen.

just isn't correct.

Comment: Oh thank you very much!

Comment: Quote *"the word »wenig« which is an adverb"* This is wrong! The word *»wenig«* is **NOT** an adverb. It is an adjective! [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/wenig), [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/wenig) You can use it as an attribute of a noun (*»die **wenigen Kunden** sind früh gegangen«*) and you can increase it (*wenig - weniger - am wenigsten*) and it will be inflected. This all is impossible for adverbs. For more details, please read [my answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/61506/1487).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast The Duden knows »wenig« only as an adverb and as a pronoun and a »Zahlwort«.  The phrase »die wenigen Kunden« is therefore not »wenig« as an adjective (according to the Duden) but rather an article or »Zahlwort«.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast But I agree that opinions on this matter obviously differ and Duden, Wiktionary and DWDS don't share a common view.  Given that the Duden is not just any source but rather a very canonical one, I tend to agree with it.  Also, I think that the question here about the phrase »eine wenigere […] Aufgabenteilung« shows quite clearly that the Duden has a valid point:  This phrase just isn't possible.  You just cannot combine »wenige« like an adjective with singular nouns (like »Aufgabenteilung«).  It only works with plurals: »die wenige(re)n Aufgabenteilungen«.

Comment: @Alfe: Zahlwörter können nicht gesteigert werden. Ein Dreieck kann nicht *"dreier"* Ecken als ein anderes haben, und kein Dreieck hat *"am dreisten"* Ecken. Und das gilt für alle Zahlwörter. Bezüglich Singular/Plural: In meiner Antwort steht der Satz *»Das wenige Essen war sehr teuer.«* Bestimme den Numerus von *»das wenige Essen«* Beispiele aus Wiktionary: *wenig Effekt, wenig Aussagekraft.* Beispiele aus DWDS: *wenig Publikum, wenig Verkehr, wenig Zucker* aber auch *wenig Erfahrung.* ...

Comment: ... Der Grund, warum das Adjektiv *wenig* kein Attribut von *Aufgabenteilung* sein kann, ist ein anderer: Eine Aufgabenteilung existiert, oder sie existiert nicht. Davon kann es nicht viel oder wenig geben. Aber alles, dass in unterschiedlich großen Mengen vorliegen kann, kann auch *wenig* sein. Und der Duden ist schon seit 24 Jahren weder ein kanonisches noch ein normatives Wörterbuch. Der Duden ist ein in die Jahre gekommenes Nachschlagewerk, das sich mit Behauptungen wie den von dir zitierten schön langsam die eigene Reputation kaputt macht.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Given your posted answer I'm not surprised about your position (a bit about how quickly the ad hominem against the Duden popped up, though).  No offense meant, as I said, it's a matter of opinions and we won't come to an agreement.  You follow Wiktionary's and DWDS's, I understand the Duden's as well.  »Wenig« seems to be an adjective because it can be raised to comparative like an adjective.  It also appears to be a number word because it only can be applied to plurals (for many words).  So it has features of both, so I can understand both positions.

Answer (score 2):

The German word *»wenig«* is not an adverb, it is an adjective. The main difference between adverbs and adjectives is, that adverbs only can be used in adverbial usage, while adjectives can be used adverbial, predicative and as an attribute.

- adverbial usage

  - adjective

    > Die Frau singt **schön.** The woman sings **beautifully.**
  - adverb

    > Die Frau singt **oft.** The woman sings **often.**
- predicative usage

  - adjective

    > Die Frau ist **schön.** The woman is **beautiful.**
  - adverb

    > wrong: <del>*Die Frau ist **oft.** The woman is **often.***</del>
- attributive usage

  - adjective

    > Die **schöne** Frau singt. The **beautiful** woman sings.
  - adverb

    > wrong: <del>*Die **ofte** Frau singt. The **often** woman sings.*</del>

In your sentence the word *»weniger«* is used as an attribute, so it can't be an adverb. It must be an adjective.

---

Adjectives can describe properties of nouns:

> Das **leise** Instrument hat einen schönen Klang.
> Das **wenige** Essen war sehr teuer.

Adjectives can describe properties of participles:

> Der **leise** sprechende Mann war blass.
> Die **wenig** essende Frau schlief etwas später ein.

Adjectives can describe properties of adverbs:

> **Hoch** oben auf den Bergen liegt schon Schnee.
> Die beiden Orte liegen nur **wenig** auseinander.

But adjectives also can describe properties of other adjectives:

> Der **grell** rote Ball lag in der Wiese.
> Man muss ab und zu auch mal eine **wenig** gerechte Aufgabenteilung im Beruf hinnehmen.

Note, that in the last two examples the bold marked adjectives do not describe a property of the noun, but a property of the adjective that stands immediately after them.

Also note, that adjectives, that are attributes of other adjectives, are not inflected, since they do not belong to a noun. Only adjectives that are attributes of nouns will be inflected.

Compare:

> 1. Der **grell** rote Ball lag in der Wiese.
> 2. Der **grelle** rote Ball lag in der Wiese.

In 1 the word *grell* (*glaring*) describes a property of the adjective *rot* (*red*).
In 2 the word *grelle* describes a property of the noun *Ball* (*ball*).

Since in English adjectives never are inflected, both German sentences translate to the same English sentence, but in the English sentence it is ambiguous if the adjective *glaring* is bound to *red* or to *ball:*

> The glaring red ball lay in the meadow.

This can mean:

> 1. *attribute of an adjective:* The ball, that is glaring red, lay in the meadow.
> 2. *attribute of a noun:* The glaring and red ball lay in the meadow.

---

And, like many adjectives (but almost no adverb), the adjective *»wenig«* not only exists in its positive form, but also in a comparative and a superlative form:

- positiv: wenig (Engl: *little*)
- comparative: weniger (*less*)
- superlative: am wenigsten (*least*)

And in your sentence it is used in the comparative form:

> Man muss ab und zu auch mal eine **weniger** gerechte Aufgabenteilung im Beruf hinnehmen.
> From time to time one has to accept a **less** fair division of tasks in one's job.

Also in the english translation the adjective *little* in its comparative form *less* does not describe a property of the noun *division.* The adjective *less* describes a property of the adjective *fair.*

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Dein mittlerer Teil unterschätzt die englische Sprache ein bißchen. Sie kann sehr wohl ausdrücken, dass ein Ball grell-rot (*glaringly red*) oder grell **und** rot (*glaring, red*) ist.